# filesize returns zero when read from remote server using VBscript

Tags: vbscript, ftp, filesize

I am trying to read a file size from remote server using ftp credentials in Vb script,i have the following code below which returns remote file size zero.Anythink which i done wrong?.Please help me,Your solution could be appreciated here

```
    Dim fso, folder1, folder2, folder2a
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set folder2a = fso.GetFolder("C\samples\")
ftpFolderString = "ftp://xxx:yyyy@www.hostname.com/Folder"
targetFoldder = "C\samples"
Dim SH, txtFolderToOpen, thing
Set SH = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
Set folder1 = SH.NameSpace(ftpFolderString)
Set folder2 = SH.NameSpace(targetFoldder)
For Each item In folder1.items
MsgBox item.size
For Each item2 In folder2a.Files
  If item2.size< item.Name Then
    ..do stuff             
  End IF
     Next
Next
```

I am getting remote file size zero.Could you pl help me what i went wrong in that script

Answer (score 0):

While the docs don't say anything, it's common that some object properties aren't available on remote items. Try using the fso object size property. It is a completely different mechanism.

From Help

```
Function ShowFolderSize(filespec)

   Dim fso, f, s

   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   Set f = fso.GetFolder(filespec)

   s = UCase(f.Name) & " uses " & f.size & " bytes."

   ShowFolderSize = s

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 3 a typo?

```
"C\samples\"
```

Should be

```
"C:\samples\"
```